# Datatables align center

Tags: html, datatables

I have a table on a page and retrieving and displaying contents using datatables. But the columns are not aligned to the center. This is how it looks right now. [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2rMZ.png) 
. This is how I am creating the table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
manageMemberTable = $("#manageMemberTable").DataTable({


    "ajax": "php_actionsms/retrieve.php",
    "order": [[0,'desc']]
});
```

Html Code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <center><h1 class="page-header">TMTRO Iloilo <small>Accident Report Records</small> </h1></center>

            <div class="removeMessages"></div>
            <br /> <br /> <br />

            <table class="table table-responsive " id="manageMemberTable">                  
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Recipient</th>
                        <th>Recipient Number</th>
                        <th>Place</th>
                        <th>Officer</th>
                        <th>Date&Time</th>                                              
                        <th>Sent to Icer</th>
                        <th>Option</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you try `text-align:center;` ?

Answer (score 7):

add this when defining datatables:

```
"columnDefs": [
    {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"}
]
```

add this to your CSS:

```
 th.dt-center, td.dt-center { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: where do I add this? Bootstrap CSS or Datatables CSS?

Comment: you add that to your own CSS, that's a very basic question, look at this link https://datatables.net/examples/index and study first the basics of datatables